# select previous rows and calculate

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables

1. Loan
2. Loan_Payments

in `MS Access`

**Loan includes**

1. Ref_Loan
2. Amount_Loan

**Loan_Payments includes**

1. Ref_Loan
2. Amount_Paid
3. Date

**Loan Table**

```
Ref_Loan    Loan_Amount
loan 1      12000
loan 2      24000
loan 3      5000
```

**Loan_Payments**

```
Ref_Loan Amount_Paid Date
loan 1     1000    01/01/2011
loan 1     1000    01/02/2011
loan 1     1000    01/03/2011
loan 2     1000    01/01/2011
loan 2     1000    01/02/2011
```

I want an out put that will show like this;

```
Ref_loan    Amount_Paid    Date      Balance
loan 1      1000         01/01/2011  11000
loan 1      1000         01/02/2011  10000
loan 1      1000         01/03/2011   9000
loan 2      1000         01/01/2011  23000
loan 2      1000         01/02/2011  22000
loan 3                                5000
```

Comment: You need to provide more information such as what kind of application will do this, and how you need to show your data? (Export to excel, on gridview..). Your tag contains SQL, question contains Access. Please refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

Access query:

```
select L.Ref_Loan, P.Amount_Paid, P.Date,
    L.Loan_Amount - DSum("Amount_Paid", "Loan_Payment",
    "Ref_Loan=" & L.Ref_Loan & " AND Date<= #" & Format(P.Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#")
from Loan AS L
left join Loan_Payments AS P on P.Ref_Loan = L.Ref_Loan
ORDER BY L.Ref_Loan, P.Date
```

However, if you are using Jet from C#, DSum may not work.  In which case, write out the proper SQL in full

```
select L.Ref_Loan, P.Amount_Paid, P.Date,
    L.Loan_Amount - (
        SELECT SUM(P2.amount_paid)
        FROM Loan_Payment AS P2
        WHERE P2.Ref_Loan=L.Ref_Loan
        AND P2.Date <= P.Date)
from Loan AS L
left join Loan_Payments AS P on P.Ref_Loan = L.Ref_Loan
ORDER BY L.Ref_Loan, P.Date
```

Comment: @Ryan I have added "AS" for the aliases, I think you may have to add some brackets as well in the ON clause.  Haven't got Access up but it is really picky